# Fill DataGrid Based on selected item of another datagrid

Tags: wpf

I have 2 datagrids. Data should be fetched from the database according to the selection criteria based on selection of 1st datagrid.  It needs to populate the 2nd datagrid.

Any best way to do in wpf?

This is code of my xaml:

```
<cmcCtl:CmcDataGrid x:Name="QueueSearchCampusGrid"
                                            Canvas.Left="0"
                                            Canvas.Top="0"
                                            Width="572"
                                            Height="114"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                            SelectionChanged="CmcDataGrid_OnSelectionChanged"
                                            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedValue}"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding ProspectiveCampusList}">
                            <cmcCtl:CmcDataGrid.Columns>
                                <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="False"
                                                            CanUserResize="False"
                                                            CanUserSort="False"
                                                            ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"
                                                            IsReadOnly="False">
                                    <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DataGridCell}">
                                            <EventSetter Event="UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" />
                                            <EventSetter Event="UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CampusCode}"
                                                            ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"
                                                            Header="Campus Code" />
                                <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CampusDescription}"
                                                            ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"
                                                            Header="Campus" />
                            </cmcCtl:CmcDataGrid.Columns>
                        </cmcCtl:CmcDataGrid>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxCampusHeadSelect"
                                  Canvas.Left="4"
                                  Canvas.Top="4"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                  Content=""
                                  Checked="CheckBoxHeadSelect_Checked"
                                  IsThreeState="False"
                                  Unchecked="CheckBoxHeadSelect_Unchecked" />
                    </Canvas>
                    <Canvas Grid.Row="3"
                            Width="572"
                            Height="112"
                            Margin="0,5,0,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <cmcCtl:CmcDataGrid x:Name="QueueSearchProgramVersionGrid"
                                            Canvas.Left="0"
                                            Canvas.Top="0"
                                            Width="572"
                                            Height="114"
                                            SelectionMode="Single"
                                            SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding QueueSearchProgramVersionList}">
                            <cmcCtl:CmcDataGrid.Columns>
                                <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="False"
                                                            CanUserResize="False"
                                                            CanUserSort="False"
                                                            ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"
                                                            IsReadOnly="False">
                                    <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DataGridCell}">
                                            <EventSetter Event="UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" />
                                            <EventSetter Event="UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
                                        </Style>
                                    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                                </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Width="85"
                                                            Binding="{Binding CampusCode}"
                                                            ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"
                                                            Header="Campus Code" />
                                <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Width="100"
                                                            Binding="{Binding CampusDescription}"
                                                            ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"
                                                            Header="Campus" />
                                <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProgramVersionCode}"
                                                            ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"
                                                            Header="Program Code" />
                                <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ProgramVersionDescription}"
                                                            ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"
                                                            Header="Program Version" />
                            </cmcCtl:CmcDataGrid.Columns>
                        </cmcCtl:CmcDataGrid>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxProgramVersionHeadSelect"
                                  Canvas.Left="4"
                                  Canvas.Top="4"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                  Content=""
                                  Checked="CheckBoxHeadSelect_Checked"
                                  IsThreeState="False"
                                  Unchecked="CheckBoxHeadSelect_Unchecked" />
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
```

This is code of my model class:

```
public ShoppingSheetQueueSearchClient SelectedValue
{
    get
    { 
        return _selectedValue; 
    }

    set
    {
        if (_selectedValue == value) return;
        _selectedValue = value;
        BindQueueSearchProgramVersionGridControl();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried using SelectedItem.Selecteditem changed grid event.But not successfull.

Comment: Can you post your code.

Comment: Added the code and Xaml.